# Nvidia-persistenced in syslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, syslog

On boot, I saw multiple lines about nvidia flashing on-screen before the X login screen. Looking at the /var/log/syslog, grep showed many entries about  nvidia-persistenced on boot. It seems to start and stop in some kind of loop  (grep 'persistenced: Started' /var/log/syslog | wc -l == 469 just for tonight's boot). Here is a sample:

> Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation snapd[953]: udevmon.go:190: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device "/sys/cred_jar(4505:nvidia-persistenced.service)"
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Verbose syslog connection opened
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Now running with user ID
>   124 and group ID 130
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Started (3593)
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: device 0000:09:00.0 - registered
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Local RPC service initialized
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Received signal 15
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Socket closed.
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: PID file unlocked.
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: PID file closed.
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
>   Jan 30 19:06:37 workstation nvidia-persistenced: Shutdown (3593)

Is this normal behaviour? What is happening?

Comment: I have the same problem, where the service dies from signal 15, restarts, dies, etc. Did you figure out a solution?